# AWS Lambda Chalice app not receiving request payload

Tags: python, rest, aws-lambda, urllib, chalice

I have a small lambda function that I am creating with AWS Chalice in Python.
When testing locally all works as intended and my test request works perfectly.
However when running `chalice deploy` and then testing the same request to the hosted API I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/chalice/app.py", line 1913, in _get_view_function_response
File "/var/task/app.py", line 34, in questions
payload = parse_qs(body)['data'][0]
KeyError: 'data'
```

app.py is as follows

```py
# other imports
from urllib import parse_qs

def encode_payload(payload):
    '''encodes generic payload'''
    return base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(payload)).decode('utf-8')

def decode_payload(payload):
    '''decodes generic payload'''
    return pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(payload))

app = Chalice(app_name='markthis-api')

@app.route('/questions', methods=['GET'], content_types=['application/json'])
def questions():
    style = app.current_request.query_params['style']
    body = app.current_request.raw_body.decode()

    payload = parse_qs(body)['data'][0]
    img = decode_payload(payload)

    stuff = find_questions(img, style)

    return {'pickle': encode_payload(stuff)}
```

test.py

```
def api_request(img, style):
    url = f'https://api-code-etc.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/api/questions?style={style}'
    #url = f'http://localhost:8000/questions?style={style}'

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    payload = {'data': encode_payload(img)}

    return requests.get(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

I am new to AWS and Chalice and have no idea what is causing this issue.
The API has one other endoint '/' which returns `{'hello': 'world'}`.
This works fine when deployed.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

When Content-Type is "application-json" the preferred method is using `.json_body`. Instead of;

```
body = app.current_request.raw_body.decode()
```

Doing this might resolve the problem:

```
body = app.current_request.json_body
```